# I am getting an error while try to use tensorflow to recognize faces

Tags: javascript, jquery, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow to check if image has a human face
after user upload a photo

however I am getting this error:

RegPage.php:205 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mediapipeFacemesh')

will appreciate what I am doing wrong with code example.

```
attaching relevant code:

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks- 
detection"></script>

<script>


document.getElementById('take-photo').setAttribute('capture', 'environment');

// Change label text for taking a selfie photo
document.querySelector('label[for="take-photo"]').innerText = 'צלם תמונת סלפי:';

async function validateSelfie(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.onload = async () => {
        // Load Face-API.js model
        const model = await faceLandmarksDetection.load(
            faceLandmarksDetection.SupportedPackages.mediapipeFacemesh
        );

        // Detect faces in the image
        const predictions = await model.estimateFaces({
            input: img,
        });

        // Check if at least one face is detected
        if (predictions.length > 0) {
            alert("has face.");
            // Proceed with form submission or further processing
        } else {
            alert("No Face");
            // Optionally, reset the photo input field to allow re-capturing the selfie
            document.getElementById('take-photo').value = '';
        }
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    }
 }


// Function to handle photo preview
function previewPhoto(input) {
var preview = document.getElementById('photo-preview');
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        preview.src = e.target.result;
        preview.style.display = 'block';
        validateSelfie(input); // Call the function to validate the selfie

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  } else {
    preview.src = '#';
    preview.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```